# Translation of an article 

Tags: quantum-mechanics, physics, mp.mathematical-physics, reference-request, bibliography

I need to read this article

"On the spectrum of an energy operator for atoms with fixed nuclei in subspaces corresponding to irriducible representations of permutation groups"

authors:G.Zhislin, A. Sigalov
(Izv. Akad. Nauk. SSSR Ser. Mat. 1965 29 pagg 853-860)

but I've found it in Russian only. Is there anyone who knows the existence of a translation of this article?

Comment: A little websleuthing leads to http://iopscience.iop.org/1064-5632/ which indicates that *Izv. Akad. Nauk.* started being translated into English in 1967 -- two years too late for the OP's request.

Answer (score 6):

Download the PDF file of the original article here: http://www.mathnet.ru/php/getFT.phtml?jrnid=im&paperid=3076&volume=29&year=1965&issue=4&fpage=835&what=fullt&option_lang=eng
and apply Google Translate to it.
The result seems fairly readable, but you have to consult
the original every time you see a formula.
For example, here is the translation of the first paragraph of the introduction:

> In this paper, we study the spectrum of a differential operator operator H (1.2), the Hilbert space of complex- Sn valued functions of the independent variables that have defined tion permutation symmetry. For n = 1, a complete description of the spectrum of H can be found in textbooks on quantum mechanics [See, eg, ( n )]. In this case, the permutation symmetry does not make sense. For n> 1 the last result on the structure of the spectrum of H is given in ( 3 ), Where it is established that without the symmetry of the operator H has an infinite sequence ABILITY isolated of finite eigenvalues convergent schihsya to some fx <^ 0 *. All points lying to the right of \ x, form limit spectrum. However, the symmetry properties of the few found in ( 3 ) Own physically realizable value. *

Answer (score 0):

The articles of Zhislin are on the site

http://www.mathnet.ru/php/person.phtml?&personid=11636&option_lang=eng

If there was a translation, it would be on this site.

Comment: I knew this site; there are only Russian articles

Comment: @Sue: Then you can only connect with the autors; most likely, they have a translation of their results (e.g., for some survey).

Comment: Boris, one author did a survey in Uspekhi, http://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=rm&paperid=5726&option_lang=eng which was translated. 

Comment: Also translated: http://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=im&paperid=2162&option_lang=eng  as it was after 1967...

Comment: @Will Jagy : I know, but Sue needs another paper